# Python for Data Analysis, Chapter 2, first example

Tags: python, ipython

I'm following along with the examples in a translated version of Wes McKinney's "Python for Data Analysis" and I was blocked in first example of Chapter 2

I think my problem arose because I saved a data file in a wrong path. is that right?

[image]

I stored a file, `usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt`, in `C:\Users\HRR`
and also stored folder, `pydata-book-mater`, that can be downloaded from http://github.com/pydata-book in `C:\Users\HRR\Anaconda2\Library\bin`.

Comment: use full path - it can run in different folder than you expect.

Comment: BTW: check `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())` to see in which folder it runs

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

You might change the location you save your File or eddit the path you give to your code in Line 10. Since you're yousing relativ Paths i guess your script runs in C:\Users\HRR\Anaconda2\Library\bin, which means you have to go back to C:\Users\HRR or use an absolute Path ... or move the File, but hell you don't want to move a file every time you want to open it, like moving word files into msoffice file to open it, so try to change the Path.

And allways try harder ;)

Answer (score 0):

In python `open()` will open from the `current directory` down unless given a full path (in linux that starts with `/` and windows `<C>://`). In your case the command is open the folder `ch02` in the directory the script is running from and then open `usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt` in that folder.

Since you are storing the text file in `C:\Users\HRR\usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt` and you did not specify the directory of the script. I recommend the following command instead `open(C:\\Users\\HRR\\usagov_bitly_data2012-03-16-1331923249.txt)`

Note: the double `\` is to escape the characters and avoid tabs and newlines showing up in the path.